# Custom UDF written in Pyspark giving output as "java.lang.Object"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have written a custom transformer class `POSWordTagger`. My `_transform()` method code is,

```
def _transform(self, dataset):

    def f(s):
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(s)
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        return pos_tags

t = ArrayType(StringType())
out_col = self.getOutputCol()
in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]
return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(f, t)(in_col))
```

I am calling my transformer class as follows,

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sentenceDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1, "Logistic regression models are neat")
  ], ["label", "sentence"])

pos_tagger = POSWordTagger(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="pos")

pos_output=pos_tagger.transform(sentenceDataFrame)
pos_output.select("pos").show()
```

I am getting the output as,

```
+--------------------+
|                 pos|
+--------------------+
|[[Ljava.lang.Obje...|
|[[Ljava.lang.Obje...|
|[[Ljava.lang.Obje...|
+--------------------+
```

Even though I am passing the schema as `ArrayType(StringType())`, I am getting the Object reference as the output. But if I return only the `tokens` as output instead of the `pos_tags` from my `_transform()` method, I am getting the output correctly, that is, a list of tokens. Can anyone please let me know what am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. My environment is Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at below example, `pos_tag` returns `list(tuple(string))`:

```
>>> text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)


[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

So problem in your code looks here `ArrayType(StringType())`, So it should be `ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType()))`

###### Answer For Comment

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
def flattenArray(obj):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, obj)

pos_output.select(F.udf(flattenArray, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))("pos").alias("pos")).show(truncate = False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above solution works. But not I am getting the output as a "[WrappedArray()]" How can we just obtain a list with the tokenized word and its POS tag? I want to pass it as a feature, so I cannot use the output in the above format. Can you please let me know how can I get a plain list of tuples as an output instead of WrappedArray?

Comment: look at answer Modified

Comment: Regarding the solution, I have one more concern. I need the output in the list format as a return output of the call to _transform() method. Here the UDF is working in the select() method after the transformation is already done, which previously gave the output as WrappedArray. How can we use this UDF inside the _transform() method? I am already using a UDF for pos tags, so where should I use the above UDF so that when the call to _transform() is done, I get the output as a plain list, as desired?

Comment: same way in udf, return statement should be like  ``return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, pos_tags)`` and  ``t`` should be ``t = ArrayType(StringType())``

Comment: Awesome.Thank you :)

Comment: Is there any chance do you know the answer to this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111624/is-there-a-way-to-persist-or-save-the-pipeline-model-in-pyspark-1-6

Comment: @Alvin I have experience over spark sql data frames only, Checked question and seems no chance from my side.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, do you know the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748029/pyspark-how-to-covert-column-with-ljava-lang-object)?

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk I looked at this, there seems to be a problem at creating parquet file. It's good if you can solve by looking at file creation, else I will find some time help you.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, thank you. You are right. Problem was with file creation.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, you know - I did not resolve the exact issue I want to solve in my question. However, I know the problem is with file creation.

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk do you need my help to resolve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198921/discussion-between-jaroslav-bezdk-and-rakesh-kumar).