# Is there a way to persist or save the pipeline model in pyspark 1.6?

Tags: python, pyspark, pipeline

I understand that this is a duplicate question which was asked here [saving pipeline model in pyspark 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987227/how-to-store-cvmodel-or-pipeline-in-pyspark-1-6) but there is still no definite answer to it. Can anyone please suggest anything?

joblib or cPickle doesn't work as it gives the same error which is given in the previous link. Is there a way to save the pipeline in PySpark 1.6 or there isn't? The questions that I saw regarding model persistence were mainly related to persisting ML models. Saving a pipeline is the altogether differnt issue. Is there any hack that is available? I need the Python (v2.7) implementation. Any help is appreciated. I am using the RandomForestClassifier from pyspark.ml as a classification algorithm and my environment is Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7 (if this is of any help)

Comment: Have you tried converting the object into an RDD and saving it as a pickle file from that RDD using `sc.saveAsPickleFile(rdd, 'path')` ? A similar method works in scala.

Comment: I am not sure how can we convert an object of type PipelineModel to an RDD. sc.parallelize() doesn't work as it requires a list as an input I suppose. Is there any other way to convert the object into an RDD? 
I have tried using the dill library as follows,

import dill as p
with open("temp.pkl","wb") as f:
    p.dump(model,f)

But it gave me max recursion depth error. I tried changing the depth, but no success. 
I have tried the cloudpickle library, still not able to achieve the goal. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am sorry. If it is pyspark 1.6, then it is not possible to save models or pipelines. That feature was introduced in the Scala version though. They have added this feature to pyspark only in 2.0.