# PySpark: How to covert column with Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs, java

I created data frame in PySpark by reading data from HDFS like this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/parquet')
```

I expect the data frame to have two column of strings:

```
+------------+------------------+
|my_column   |my_other_column   |
+------------+------------------+
|my_string_1 |my_other_string_1 |
|my_string_2 |my_other_string_2 |
|my_string_3 |my_other_string_3 |
|my_string_4 |my_other_string_4 |
|my_string_5 |my_other_string_5 |
|my_string_6 |my_other_string_6 |
|my_string_7 |my_other_string_7 |
|my_string_8 |my_other_string_8 |
+------------+------------------+
```

However, I get `my_column` column with some strings starting with `[Ljava.lang.Object;`, looking like this:

```
>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------+------------------+
|my_column                    |my_other_column   |
+-----------------------------+------------------+
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@7abeeeb6 |my_other_string_1 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@5c1bbb1c |my_other_string_2 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@6be335ee |my_other_string_3 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@153bdb33 |my_other_string_4 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@1a23b57f |my_other_string_5 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@3a101a1a |my_other_string_6 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@33846636 |my_other_string_7 |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@521a0a3d |my_other_string_8 |
+-----------------------------+------------------+

>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- my_column: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_other_column: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, `my_other_column` column is looking as expected. Is there any way, how to convert objects in `my_column` column to humanly readable strings?

Comment: can you add df.printSchema() to see what kind of datatype is shown for my_column?

Comment: @Yuva, I added it into code section of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Jaroslav,

I tried with the following code, and have used a sample parquet file from [here](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/sample-data/parquet).  I am able to get the desired output from the dataframe, can u please chk your code using the code snippet below and also sample file referred above to see if there's any other issue:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Read a Parquet file").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet('E:\\...\\..\\userdata1.parquet')
df.show(10)
df.printSchema()
```

Replace the path to your HDFS location.

Dataframe output for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. However, I do not think there is a problem with reading a parquet data. The data I read from HDFS consists of more columns and each of them, except the one I have pointed out in question, is OK. So, it means, the problem is with the one and only column called `my_column`.